# Showing Key-Value attribute of a File added using java.nio.file.attribute.UserDefinedFileAttributeView

Tags: java

I want to show Key-Value attribute of a CSV file which is added 
using **java.nio.file.attribute. UserDefinedFileAttributeView** interface of java.
I can add attribute to CSV file and can read it successfully but I am not able to show this in the "Property Details Dialog" i.e **Test.csv=>Right Click=>Properties=>Details=>** (Test.csv in my case).

Please help me..